# Intransitive use of the verb to trigger

Tags: grammaticality, transitivity

The Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary of English states that "to trigger" is a transitive verb. Therefore it would be incorrect to state "An alarm triggers". We have to say "X triggers the alarm" or "the alarm is triggered".
I have seen multiple occasions where "to trigger" is used as an intransitive verb. Like in "In that case the alarm triggers. Is that correct English ?
I think it is not. Is that so ?

Comment: "We were getting close ... then the alarm triggers! Run I yell."

Comment: I wonder whether there is a *device vs person* distinction at play here. All sorts of devices can be *triggered*, but it sounds odd to say “He triggered” even though one might allow “She triggered him when the quote was approved”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was interested in which dictionaries give the intransitive definition, I checked a few:

Here are the ones that don't list an intransitive use:

- [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trigger)
- [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trigger)
- [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trigger)
- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trigger)
- [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trigger_1)
- [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trigger) (Surprised me, as I thought this was a very permissive one)

Dictionaries that DO list an intransitive definition:

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trigger):

> 6. to release a trigger.
> 7. to become active; activate.

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trigger):

> to release a mechanical trigger

[Random House Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trigger?s=t) (From dictionary.com):

> 7. to release a trigger.
> 8. to become active; activate.

Dictionaries I couldn't check because I don't have an account or subscription:

- [OED](http://www.oed.com/)
- [Macquarie Dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/)

Whether you can use a verb intransitively or not is a tricky subject.

Comment: OED has an intransitive sense for *trigger*, originally used in electronics and signal processing, dated to 1933.

Comment: I checked the OED for you and it has the following: "*intr.* Of an electronic device: to change state in response to a momentarily applied signal."

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary.com cites the intransitive usage:

[Trigger:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trigger)

> verb (used without object)
>
> 1) to release a trigger
>
> 2) to become active; activate.

From: [The CNC Toolbox: Computer Numerical Control](https://books.google.it/books?id=EI3gAAAAMAAJ&q=%22alarm%20triggered%22&dq=%22alarm%20triggered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqIztgIbdAhWLtIsKHVzBCskQ6AEIUDAJ)

> The alarm triggered when some switch contact opened a normally closed alarm circuit.

Comment: Very common normal to use the intransitive form. The smoke alarm triggered when I burnt/burned the toast. The smoke alarm was triggered when I burnt/burned the toast. The burglar alarm triggered when the window was forced open. Your sick absences have triggered the formal attendance procedure.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  - yes, curiously very few dictionaries cite the intransitive usage.

Comment: @user070221, the reason why some, but only a few, dictionaries cite the intransitive usage is probably that *to trigger* is right now in the process of becoming ergative. The descriptivists are rushing to take note of the new usage, while the prescriptivists are resisting it.